# EMGU doesn't work for me - cannot open local image

Tags: vb.net, emgucv

I am  currently working with EmguCV in VB.NET.
My program can't open the image, and I don't understand why.

Note: the line to open the file was converted by a software from C# to VB.NET .

What might be the problem in the code?

```
Imports Emgu.CV
Imports Emgu.CV.Util
Imports Emgu.CV.Structure

Module analyse

' module général d'analyse
' on assume que les images soient dans le dossier /images/...
' les images ont déjà été tresholdé par le backend

Sub detect_lines()

    Dim RhoRes As Double = 2
    Dim Threshold As Double = 100
    Dim MinLineWidth As Double = 1
    Dim linegap As Integer = 3
    Dim ThetaRes As Double = Math.PI / 180

    Dim image = CvInvoke.cvLoadImage("frame3.jpg", 1)
    Dim img As New Image(Of Bgr, Byte)("frame3.jpg")

    Dim Linez()() As LineSegment2D = img.HoughLinesBinary(RhoRes, ThetaRes, Threshold, 0, 0)

    If Linez(0).Length = 0 Then 'Greater than or equal to
        For i = 0 To Linez(0).Length - 1

            If Linez(0)(i).Length = 10 And Linez(0)(i).Length = 30 Then 'Greater than and less than or equal to
                img.Draw(Linez(0)(i), New Bgr(0, 255, 0), 3)
            End If

            If Linez(0)(i).Length = 30 And Linez(0)(i).Length = 60 Then 'Greater than and less than or equal to
                img.Draw(Linez(0)(i), New Bgr(255, 0, 0), 3)
            End If

            If Linez(0)(i).Length = 60 Then
                img.Draw(Linez(0)(i), New Bgr(0, 0, 255), 3)
            End If

        Next
    End If

    MsgBox(Linez.ToString)

End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Does the program throw an exception? If so at which line and what was the exception type and error message?

Comment: please check if the image already copied in the /bin directory or not ?

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i do not continue on this way...